# Micro SD cards & T-flash?

Tags: sd

Something interesting I've noticed with cheap devices from China (such as iPhone clones and digital cameras and the like) is that the manuals always specify they are "T-flash" (TransFlash) compatible, instead of "microSD" or "SD" compatible. Is this to get around paying the $3k/yr license fee, or is it something else entirely? The devices seem compatible with microSD as well as TransFlash cards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to pay royalties to the SD card people if my device "just happens" to be compatible with SD cards?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5628/do-i-need-to-pay-royalties-to-the-sd-card-people-if-my-device-just-happens-to-b) This is just an extension of a previous question, they should be grouped together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that T-flash and TransFlash are just the name of the microSD spec before it was adopted by the Secure Digital standards body.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroSD agrees

Comment: I suppose that T-Flash does not include the secure part of SD cards (instructions and protected memory area). But not sure.